# create the same function in another language

Tags: c#, java, r

Sorry for the previous question, but I was so confused and stressed :S.

I have this function in R:

```
shift <- function(d, k) rbind( tail(d,k), head(d,-k), deparse.level = 0 )
```

and this data frame:

```
A B value
1 1 0.123
2 1 0.213
3 1 0.543
1 2 0.313
2 2 0.123
3 2 0.412
```

this function will transform this data frame to (in case k=1) :

```
A B value
3 2 0.412
1 1 0.123
2 1 0.213
3 1 0.543
1 2 0.313
2 2 0.123
```

Code:

```
string[] data = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt");
decimal[,] numbers = new decimal[data.Length, 3];
                 
for(int x = 0; x < data.Length; x++)
{
    string[] temp = data[x].Split(' ');
                                
     for(int y = 1; y < temp.Length; y++)
     {
        numbers[x,y] = Convert.ToDecimal(temp[y]);
     }
}
```

that's the code i'm using to get the values from the text file , but i want to create the function that will rotate this table.

I want to make the same function for a text file in Java or C#.

How this can be done?

I'm storing the data in C# in a 2D array: `decimal[,]`

## UPDATE:

your function will rotate them like the previous example, what i want to do is this:

i have this table:

```
 A B value
    1 1 0.123
    2 1 0.213
    3 1 0.543
    1 2 0.313
    2 2 0.123
    3 2 0.412
```

i want it to become(in case of shift by 2) :

> ```
> A B value
> 3 1 0.543
> 1 2 0.313
> 2 2 0.123
> 3 2 0.412
> 1 1 0.123
> 2 1 0.213
> ```

Comment: What data structure are you using in C# or Java to represent the data? The operation appears to move the last row to be the first row and push every other row down by 1. Is that right?

Comment: @David Heffernan :  i'm using a normal table to read the data from a text file using : string[] data = File.ReadAllLines("test.txt"); split the values by ' ' and then transforming it to decimal array using : numbers[x,y] = Convert.ToDecimal(temp[y]); inside a for loop

Comment: May I suggest you to post some code, so we can see what's wrong?

Comment: @Roberto Aloi :  i added the code that i'm using to get the data from text file

Comment: @smack: your code indentation was "creative" (i.e., *terrible*) enough to make your code unreadable. I have fixed this, but next time, lease take the effort to fix it yourself.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels : sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do what you want but I must admit I'm not that familiar with C# so I'd expect there to be a more idiomatic form with less looping:

```
    static decimal[,] Rotate(decimal[,] input, int k)
    {
        int m = input.GetLength(0);
        int n = input.GetLength(1);
        decimal[,] result = new decimal[m, n];
        for (int i=0; i<m; i++)
        {
            int p = (i + k) % m;
            if (p < 0)
                p += m;
            for (int j=0; j<n; j++)
                result[p, j] = input[i, j];
        return result;
    }
```

Regarding your update, that is handled by passing a negative value for `k`. For your example pass `k=-2`.

Comment: @David Heffernan : hi , a first look and try showed that it gave the needed results , thanks , but i must do further tests to make sure it will do it , thanks

Comment: @smack well, I didn't even run it, so it's nice to know that my mental computer works!!

Comment: Funny how using the modulus is so much easier when indexing starts from zero.

Comment: @David Heffernan :  thnx , it works , but what i should i change if i want the rotation to be from the end of the table to the top ??

Comment: define precisely what you mean by that question

Comment: @David Heffernan :  this function will take k row from the end of the table and place it in it's top, what i want to change is to take k row from the top and place it at the end of the table

Comment: @smack What order do you want them added in at the top? Give me a simple example. What would the result be if you had 5 rows, r1, r2, r3, r4 and r5, and moved the bottom 2. Also, I think I already answered this question? You could consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @David Heffernan : kindly find my update in the question, you find a simple example of the change that i want

Comment: @smack I've updated the answer to match your updated question.